# Write to Windows Registry via Go

Tags: windows, winapi, registry, go

I need to write to the Windows Registry via Go, but am unable to find the mechanism to do so.

I have found that https://github.com/lxn/go-winapi provides read-only access to the Registry in the *advapi32.go* file.  I have filed a bug report requesting the ability to write to the Registry as well so it makes it into a wishlist or tasklist for someone in the future.

I think that this ability may not even exist in an existing Go library and that it needs to be created.  On the chance that it already exists, I'm asking here.  If it doesn't exist but you are interested in enhancing *go-winapi* or another similar library, please do.  Or if you know the mechanics behind writing to the registry, sharing that information so that I (or someone else) can work that into a patch for the *go-winapi* library would certainly be appreciated.

If nothing else, I'll come back here to answer this (if no one else does) if I'm able to get this added to *go-winapi* or a similar library myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found at [bitbucket.org/kardianos/service/src/service_windows.go](https://bitbucket.org/kardianos/service/src/0393d1b93afa/service_windows.go), there is working Windows Registry code along with (bonus!) Windows Service management code, too.  Here is a sample of that code:

```
var regSetKeyValueExProc = advapi.MustFindProc("RegSetValueExW")
func regSetKeyValue(h syscall.Handle, keyName string, data interface{}) error {
        var dataPtr, dataLen, dataType uintptr
        switch v := data.(type) {
        case uint32:
                dataPtr, dataLen = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&v)), 4
                dataType = _REG_DWORD
        case string:
                // The comment on MSDN regarding escaping back-slashes, are c-lang specific.
                // The API just takes a normal NUL terminated string, no special escaping required.
                dataPtr, dataLen = StringToUTF16PtrLen(v)
                dataType = _REG_SZ
        }
        r0, _, e1 := regSetKeyValueExProc.Call(
                uintptr(h),
                uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(keyName))),
                0,
                dataType,
                dataPtr,
                dataLen,
        )
        if r0 != 0 {
                return e1
        }
        return nil
}
```

Answer (score 3):

here is some sample

https://github.com/axgle/go/tree/master/regedit

Comment: This is useful, thanks.  I'll review the code.  If it's useful, I'll set this as the answer.  And then I'll make a patch for _go-winapi_ to benefit from this.  Thanks again.

Comment: It turns out that code was only a little bit helpful and was otherwise very incomplete.  I've added an answer to this question that links over to some good, working code for this purpose.  Sorry for removing the answer flag on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use WMI to read/write the registry, which is also accessible via Go.

[WMIC: Work with the registry](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wmic.php#Registry) describes how to go about doing that via the WMIC command line tool in Windows.  That can be adapted for use in any programming environment that can interface with WMI.

I'm leaving user1391070's answer as the flagged answer, but this might help someone that needs to go the WMI route.